# Neovim process spawned from fish script terminates immediately

Tags: shell, background-process, fish

I'm trying to achieve the following:

*from a fish script*, open a PDF reader as a background job. Once it is opened, spawn another `fish` process (that runs an infinite `while` loop), also as a background job.

Next, open an editor (`neovim`) and allow it to take control of the running terminal. Once `neovim` terminates, also suspend the previous 2 background jobs (`mupdf` and the other `fish` process).

My current attempt looks something along the lines of:

```
mupdf $pdfpath &                                                                                                                                            
set pid_mupdf $last_pid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
fish -c "while inotifywait ...; [logic to rebuild the pdf file..]; end" &                                                                                                                                          
set pid_sub $last_pid                                                                                                                                       
nvim $mdpath && kill -2 $pid_mudf $pid_sub
```

First I open mupdf as a background job and save its `PID` in a variable. Next I spawn the other fish process, also as a background job, and I save its `PID` as well.

Next I run `nvim` (but not as a background job, as I intend to actually control it), and after it is terminated by the user, I gracefully `kill` the previous 2 background jobs.

However this doesn't work as intended.

`mupdf` and the second `fish` process open successfully, and so does `nvim`, but it quickly closes after around half a second, after which I get the following in the controlling terminal window: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXfyr.png) (`bote` is just the filename of the script from which the lines above originate)

The 2 background processes stay running after that and I have to kill them manually.

I understand that the script is sent a `SIGHUP` because the controlling terminal now executes another application (`neovim`), but why does `neovim` close after that?

---

I also tried `disown`ing the background processes after they're spawned but that didn't help.

---

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: You should always specify the versions of all relevant programs. In this case the fish version is relevant.

Comment: Apologies, it's fish `3.0.1` on linux `4.20.8`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `$last_pid`, in fish 3, and `%last`, in fish 2, doesn't work by default in scripts. See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5036. You can "fix" this by putting `status job-control full` at the top of the script or using the `(jobs -lp)` hack that Glenn mentioned.

Regarding the background process remaining running... I can't reproduce that. It works for me. However, note that your `nvim && kill` will only run the `kill` if nvim exits with a status of zero. If you always want the kill to be run you should just unconditionally execute it. Also, your use of signal two (SIGINT) should produce the desired result but is unusual. You should use `kill -15` or just omit the signal in which case it defaults to 15 (SIGTERM).

Comment: Thanks. `nvim ; kill -15 ...` doesn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually it does work and terminates both processes, but the `inotifywait` process that the other fish process spawns still stays running for some reason...

Comment: @bool3max That is because fish job control is broken. As I told you in the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828931/terminate-child-process-as-soon-as-the-parent-fish-shell-process-terminates) you opened.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the PID incorrectly. The `$pid_mudf` and `$pid_sub` variables are empty. You want

```
set pid_mupdf (jobs -lp)
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But after `neovim` is terminated the 2 background processes remain open.