# Terminate child process as soon as the parent fish shell process terminates?

Tags: shell, process, fish

I'm spawning a `fish` shell as a background job and from it I'm spawning `inotifywait` (a process that watches a specified file and returns only once it has been changed).

Later on, however, at an unspecified point in time (at which point it's not guaranteed that `inotifywait` had returned), I'm killing the `fish` shell that spawned `inotifywait`.

My goal is for `inotifywait` to terminate automatically as soon as the PPID that spawned it terminates. Is there any way to do this?

```
fish -c "inotifywait -qq $somefile && ..." &
# time passes, inotifywait hasn't returned
kill -15 (jobs -lp)
# the fish process is now terminated, but inoyifywait remains
```

The temporary hack I'm using right now is to simply update the access time of the file being watched (with a utility such as `touch`) so that `inotifywait` would finally return.

I'm using fish `3.0.1` on linux `4.20.11`.

Comment: Why `fish`?  It seems like you want to do something like `bash -c 'trap "kill $!" 0; inotifywait .... && ... & wait;' &` so that the shell that invoked inotifywait will send it a signal as it terminates, but I'm not sure if that works in fish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use fish for any situation where normal job control semantics are expected. Fish is the best interactive shell I've ever used. It's been my primary login shell for several years. But it's job control has been broken all the way back to the first version. For fun do this:

```
fish -c 'trap "echo WTF; exit 3" TERM; sleep 666' &
kill (jobs -lp)
```

You won't see the "WTF" message and the backgrounded fish shell won't terminate. Now `ps waux | grep sleep` and kill the sleep process. You should see the "WTF" message on your terminal and your interactive shell will report the background fish has terminated.

For this type of situation the simplest solution is to just use bash/ksh/sh for the backgrounded script.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched to `bash` for this particular job.